# In Vi, how do I map ":t" equal to ":tabnew"?

Tags: vim, vi

I don't want to always type the word. it's annoying.

Comment: +1 for the wording and laziness that inspired so so many of my personal vim shortcuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is a [user-defined command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:com). Unfortunately, those can't begin with a lower-case letter, so your next best option is `:T`:

```
:commmand -nargs=* T tabnew <args>
```

Answer (score 2):

> If you don't like the existing shortcuts for the tab commands, you can add your own. For instance, if you want to make it easy to open a new tab, you might insert this into your .vimrc:
>
> `imap ,t <Esc>:tabnew<CR>`
>
> This tells Vim to set up a keymap for ,t in insert mode, to run Esc to put Vim into normal mode, then :tabnew and a carriage return to run the command.

From https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442422-vim-tips-using-tabs
See also http://dissociatedpress.net/vim-resources/vim-tips-using-vim-mappings-and-abbreviations/

Use `cmap` for command-mode mappings.

Comment: Doing ":cmap t tabnew<CR>" is going to have fairly serious unintended consequences--it will trigger every time you try to type a "t" in the :-command line.

Comment: @Heptite: Yes that wouldn't be good. I'll edit the answer to remove that example.

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the other suggestions, here is a more exact answer to your question:
I don't think it's possible completely equivalently, but this set of mappings would get you pretty close:

```
:nnoremap :t<CR>    :tabnew<CR>
:xnoremap :t<CR>    :tabnew<CR>

:nnoremap :t<Space> :tabnew<Space>
:xnoremap :t<Space> :tabnew<Space>
```

or equivalently, but [better](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapmode-x):

```
" :map in Normal and Visual modes, but not Select mode (see :help mapmode-x
:command -nargs=*  Nxmap      nmap     <args>| xmap     <args>
     com -nargs=*  Nxnoremap  nnoremap <args>| xnoremap <args>
     com -nargs=*  Nxunmap    nunmap   <args>| xunmap   <args>

:Nxnoremap :t<CR>    :tabnew<CR>
:Nxnoremap :t<Space> :tabnew<Space>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick a key you do not use under vim, like say <kbd>)</kbd>, and and remap that key to the tabnew command:

```
:map ) :tabnew^M
```

To enter the last CR (^M), type <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: or the IMHO more readable `<CR>` instead of the `^M`

Comment: @accolade: I prefer ^V^M as it is more portable but in that specific case which is about a vim feature, <CR> would be indeed simpler.

Comment: @jiliagre: interesting, could you elaborate on that portability?

Comment: @accolade: <CR> is vim specific so is not supported in the original vi command nor in other clones like elvis. ^V^M works with all of them.

Answer (score 0):

A builtin shorter alias for `:tabnew` is [`:tabe`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#:tabe), which is short for `:tabedit`, which is just synonymous to `:tabnew`.